# 56 volts from unconnected red wire when checks with meter to the black hot

Tags: electrical

I have three exterior outlets controlled by a toggle switch.

The electrician ran 2 wire (black and white) power from the switch box to 2 separate GFCI's.  The third regular outlet, protected by one of the GFCI's, was run with a piece of 3 wire from the GFCI Load to the outlet downstream. The 3rd red wire is not being used and was capped at both ends.  Capped at the GFCI box, and downstream at the other outlet box.  (Not sure why he ran a 3 wire, maybe that's what he had left.)

In any event, the third outlet is now protected from the GFCI up stream.  The problem I discovered, is when I turn the power on, I test meter from the hot side Black wire, to the Red 3rd wire, which is not attached to anything, I get 56 volts.   And when I test red to neutral, I get 7 volts. When I switch the power off, and I test hot black to red, I get no voltage, which I suspected.  But why am I getting 56 volts from hot black to unused red or 7 volts from neutral to unused red when the power is turned on?  Is this just phantom voltage?

Comment: Yes it's a phantom voltage, caused by capacitive coupling between the hot black wire and the unconnected red wire. Why do you believe there's a problem there?

Comment: Is there something that prompted you to start testing in the first place? That seems to be an odd thing to do on a whim...

Answer (score 1):

The meter is not wrong.  You've got more than 56 VAC on the black wire.  It's not showing the full 120 VAC because the red wire isn't grounded.  Yes, you're getting a "phantom" number in this case.

7 VAC red to neutral might be the "capacitative coupling" mentioned above, but again we're talking about the few electrons crossing a high-resistance meter mode.